# Cut MySQL Values using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know how to exract a value from a column (in MySQL) and cut it
using PHP. for exemple if i have this table:

```
---------------------
| id  | numbers     |
---------------------
|  1  | 25-62-122-0 |
|  2  | 1245-56     |
|  3  | 45-4658     |
---------------------
```

and i want to cut the first value of numbers(id=1) [25-62-122-0] and show it, using PHP, like this:

```
25
62
122
0
```

(every numbers before '-' per line)

Comment: `explode("-", $row['numbers'])` or if you want to just show each number on it's own line replace the dash with a br. `str_replace("-", "<br>", $row['numbers'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function in php

```
$string = "25-62-122-0";
$array = explode('-',$string);

foreach($array as $value) {

echo($value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very detailed step by step to achieve this (might be a little too detailed, but will show you the way):

```
$sql = new mysqli ('HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASS','DB');
$query = "SELECT numbers FROM table";
if ($result = $sql->query($query))
{
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
        $number[] = $row['numbers'];
}
}
    // do a var_dump($number); here to see the actual output

    foreach ($number as $a)
{
        $numbers[] = explode('-',$a);
}
     // do a var_dump($numbers); here to see the actual output

    foreach ($numbers as $b)
{
        echo $b;
}
```

To your next question:

```
 $sql = new mysqli ('HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASS','DB');
    $query = "SELECT numbers FROM table";
    if ($result = $sql->query($query))
    {
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
    {
            $number[] = $row['numbers'];
    }
    }
    foreach ($number as $a)
    {
        echo str_replace('-',' ',$a)."<br>";
    }
```